# View the file names and directories of eBooks in iTunes

Tags: itunes, ebook

I added eBooks from various directories to iTunes (without storing the books inside iTunes in Windows XP).  Is there a way to view the list of file names and directories?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your files are not in \iTunes Media\Books\ which is the default place to be when you tell iTunes to keep your media organized the they're in their original place.

How to know where that place is?

1. Go to books section in your library
2. Click the book you want
3. Get Info. You can right click or use your keyboard (<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Windows / <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Mac).
4. In the summary tab (first one loaded by default) you'll find a "Where" section at the bottom. with the path to the file.

Comment: As an aside, this works for any media file, not just eBooks, and regardless of whether you chose to let iTunes manage your folders or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I was looking for a way to get the entire list in one shot, hoping that it's stored, say, in an XML file somewhere.

Comment: Can you make another question to ask that? By the way, are you aware of the possibility of consolidating a library? (putting all the items in the same place... even if you initially didn't tell iTunes to organize it)

Comment: ozke: I much prefer the way I manage eBooks on the Kindle -- I use Calibre to organize my book collection, and use rsync to sync the entire directory (recursively) to the device.

Comment: Yeah, I'd also let people sort out their data the way they want. However, that's the way iTunes works I'm afraid. :S